# anyway to increase JVM memory when a program is running?

Tags: memory, jvm

I have a java computation program that has been running for 2 days and it seems still needs 24 hours to finish. I started the program with 5g memory due to the limitation of other jobs running simultaneously. Now, other programs have finished running, I have the extra memory for running the only remaining programming. Is there a way to increase memory to a running program in JVM? thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot increase heap size in a running JVM.

The heap sizes set at the JVM start time cannot be modified atthe runtime. The max heap size of your application can grow up to the value set by `-Xmx` parameter.

Comment: Yes. And if they would allow it this would confuse Garbage Collector terribly and it will have to resize its regions all over again causing your app to freeze for a significant amount of time, which would be like ( not really ) restarting your app all over again :-)